# Google Maps API draw a text from GeoJSON point geometry

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geojson

I've got geoJSON data like this:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", 
  "features": [{"type": "Feature",
                "properties": {"text": "Street Foo", 
                               "Font": "25", 
                               "Angle": "0.99999"},
                "geometry":{"type":"Point",
                            "coordinates":[44.4878559081156,9.76673954155489]}}
              ]
}
```

I would like to draw a text "Street Foo" with Font size 25 and 0.999 radiant angle inclination with Google Maps API.

I tried this:

```
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.4878559081156,9.76673954155489),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    testi = new google.maps.Data();
    testi.loadGeoJson('myjsonData.json');  

    // HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET TEXT, FONT AND ANGLE AND
    // DRAW THE TEXT...

    testi.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to process the GeoJson as it is loaded using the "addfeature" event, then displaying the text on the map using the third party [InfoBox library](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox)

1. either your GeoJson coordinates or your map center coordinates are backwards.

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.4878559081156,9.76673954155489),

"coordinates":[44.4878559081156,9.76673954155489]
```

a google.maps.LatLng has its coordinates in the order Latitude,Longitude, GeoJson is in the opposite order.

2. to "process" the GeoJson as it is loaded use an event listener on the [Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) `addFeature` event:

```
map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(evt) {
  if (evt.feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Point") {
    var coord = evt.feature.getGeometry().get();
    var labelText = evt.feature.getProperty("text");
    var labelFontSize = evt.feature.getProperty("Font") + "px";
    var labelAngle = evt.feature.getProperty("Angle");
  // ...
```

3. to rotate the text, code from this related question: [Show Value next to line in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879425/show-value-next-to-line-in-google-maps)

```
 var labelText = "4.32";
 var labelDiv = document.createElement("div");
 labelDiv.innerHTML = labelText;
 labelDiv.setAttribute("id", "label");
 labelDiv.setAttribute("style", "-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);     transform: rotate(45deg);");
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2dgkz6ay/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.4878559081156, 9.76673954155489),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(evt) {
    if (evt.feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Point") {


      var coord = evt.feature.getGeometry().get();
      var labelText = evt.feature.getProperty("text");
      var labelFontSize = evt.feature.getProperty("Font") + "px";
      var labelAngle = evt.feature.getProperty("Angle");
      var labelDiv = document.createElement("div");
      labelDiv.innerHTML = labelText;
      labelDiv.setAttribute("id", "label");
      labelDiv.setAttribute("style", "-ms-transform: rotate(" + labelAngle + "deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(" + labelAngle + "deg);     transform: rotate(" + labelAngle + "deg);");

      var myOptions = {
        content: labelDiv,
        boxStyle: {
          border: "none",
          textAlign: "center",
          fontSize: labelFontSize,
          width: "50px"
        },
        disableAutoPan: true,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, 0),
        position: coord,
        closeBoxURL: "",
        isHidden: false,
        pane: "mapPane",
        enableEventPropagation: true
      };

      var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions);
      ibLabel.open(map);
    }
  });

  map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  map.data.setMap(null);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "text": "Street Foo",
      "Font": "25",
      "Angle": "30.99999"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [9.76673954155489, 44.4878559081156]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will want to be using [MarkerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/reference.html)

```
function initMap(lat, lon){

    var address = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var figureLabel = document.createElement('Figure');
    var pictureLabel = document.createElement('img');
    pictureLabel.src = "../icons/custom_map_marker.png";
    var caption = document.createElement('FIGCAPTION');
    label = " :) ";
    var text = document.createTextNode(label);

    figureLabel.appendChild(pictureLabel);
    figureLabel.appendChild(caption);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('LocationMap'), {
        zoom : 17,
        center : address,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position : address,
        map : map,
        labelContent : figureLabel,
        labelClass : 'Label',
        labelAnchor : new google.maps.Point(65, 83)
    });

}
```

Is something that I've used in the past.

You'll note that the label is classed on the fourth line of the object's instantiation: `labelClass`  In your corresponding CSS, you should use `transform` to angle it appropriately.  Of course you'll want to use JQuery here, so something like `$('.Label').css('transform','rotate('+yourAngle+'deg)')`

For the coordinates, instead of using parameters, just use the two coordinates given.  So

```
var address = new google.maps.LatLng(object.eatures[0].geometry.coordinates[0],object.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1])
```

Comment: Sounds good, but how can I create MarkerWithLabel from geoJSON point geometry data?

Comment: Just plug in your variables for Address, and use JQuery to angle the Label class.  I've edited my answer to show how.